# How to acknowledge answers of TCS in the paper?

Tags: soft-question

I am researcher in a company from last 5 years.

I have received few answers on Theoretical Computer Science stack exchange regarding my current  research work. They are not the main part of the paper but some preexisting results and some are like direct observations ( or wikipedia results). I am confused what to do with these answers. I mean Do I need to approach persons who have answered my questions or Should I just write an acknowledgement in the paper.

Comment: Whether acknowledged or more, I like to explicitly mention that the interaction was facilitated by this site. Helps show impact on "real work", and that we're not all just wasting time on the internet :P.

Comment: In case you cite the result, do not forget to mention it [here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/references-to-cstheory-in-the-literature). Just for fun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the answers are anecdotic to your contributions or are merely direct observations/links to wikipedia, then acknowledgments are appropriate, no need to do more. Maybe commenting after these answers to let them know that they are acknowledged in your paper, together with a link to a preprint when available, would also be interesting for everyone in order to see how these answers were useful.

Basically I think that you can do the same with TCS answers as with interactions with your colleagues at coffee break: you judge how important of a contribution it is and you can act accordingly. Both situations are the same in my opinion, I like to view stackexchange as a way to increase the number of people you can "meet at coffee break".

Answer (score 12):

Both questions and answers on stackexchange have a cite option. Here's how this looks for Denis's answer above, for example:

[image]

And here's the bibtex entry you get:
\begin{verbatim}
@MISC {49216,
    TITLE = {How to acknowledge answers of TCS in the paper?},
    AUTHOR = {Denis (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/8953/denis)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49216 (version: 2021-07-07)},
    EPRINT = {https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49216},
    URL = {https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49216}
}
\end{verbatim}